# Question on installing eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The other day I came accross this SO question : [Bash script plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356827/bash-script-plugin-for-eclipse) , the idea is great.

So I went to the download site downloaded this plugin but I didn't install any eclipse plugin manually so I don't really have a clue how to install one.

I extracted this zip file I downloaded and it looks like this :

[image]

What should I do next, how do I install this plugin ? thank you

When I try to install it using install new software from local dir I get this error :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ShellEd 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97 (net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97)
  Missing requirement: ShellEd UI 0.0.0.201007201532 (net.sourceforge.shelled.ui 0.0.0.201007201532) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.launching [2.0.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ShellEd 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97 (net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97)
    To: net.sourceforge.shelled.ui [0.0.0.201007201532]
```

**PROBLEM 2 :**

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ShellEd 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97 (net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97)
  Missing requirement: ShellEd UI 0.0.0.201007201532 (net.sourceforge.shelled.ui 0.0.0.201007201532) requires *'bundle org.eclipse.linuxtools.man 0.0.0'* but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ShellEd 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97 (net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97)
    To: net.sourceforge.shelled.ui [0.0.0.201007201532]
```

I don't know what it means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the complete folder (ShellEd-Update-2.0.0_M3) to eclipse/dropins. You should remove the site.xml file from the destination location and - I think it's still necessary - look into the features folder and extract all *.jar files (folder name = jar file name).

But you should be able to install the plugin from a local zip file source too. The "install new software" dialog should have an option...

---

For clarification - of course, manual installation is **not recommended**. You may have trouble with missing dependencies, although OSGi is pretty robust and eclipse won't crash. Worst case: the plugin will not install (from an OSGi perspective). So if possible, use "install new software" and install plugins from the vendors internet page. If not possible: manual install, unzip the jars in feature folder and, if it still doesn't work: start eclipse with the `-console` option and check the status of the installed plugins. OSGi will tell you, if a plugin didn't start and why.

---

The error message: The `bash` plugin depends on another plugin named `ShellEd` (Version: 2.0.0.201007201532). Looks like it is not included in the `bash` distribution and so you'll have to install it first (or together with `bash`).

You can find it here: [ShellEd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/)

---

This one is also required: [Dynamic language toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) (any version between 2.0 and 3.0). This was the hint: `bundle org.eclipse.dltk.launching`

Comment: -1 for this suggestion. This will fail in 99% because dependencies are not resolved. The only valid way is either to install it via the Update UI or via Command-Line, see http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html The dropins folder is for installing plugins and features but not for update-sites and this is an update-site :)

Comment: @Tom - it's a workaround, and I did it quite often in environments, where I didn't have access to the internet and plugin providers offered nothing but archived update sites... It's not recommended, for sure, but you *can* use the content of an update site and "install" it manually. And of course - you'll have to resolve missing dependencies manually too.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've already downloaded that one and I'm trying to install it, this one : http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/files/shelled/ShellEd%202.0.0%20M3/ShellEd-Update-2.0.0_M3.zip/download, I've update my question I didn't see the full error until now. Thank you

Comment: Now I have this problem `bundle org.eclipse.linuxtools.man 0.0.0` where can I get this?I've updated my question. thank you

Answer (score 8):

I just successfully installed this using Drop-ins.  It depends on DLTK & the linux tools man page plugin.

To install int Eclipse 3.6 Helios, Help > Install New Software:

- Install DLTK Core from the Helios Repository: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
- Install the LinuxTools Man Page plugin from: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update
- Download the ShellEd Update Site Zip, point the Update UI at the Archive and Install

Answer (score 4):

Open Eclipse. Help->Install new software.
Add a new site, which should be local and point to your directory shown above.
Install the features it offers.
(Some of these options differ slightly in versions of Eclpse, I'm using 3.6.1 and that's how they are named there.)

Comment: Do you have the exact error message, or even better, your error log?

Comment: Just noticed the editing of your question. You need to follow the instructions here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PluginInstallHelp to get the org.eclipse.linuxtools.man plug-in. THEN retry installing the shelled stuff, hopefully that will satisfy all of the dependencies

Comment: I needed to add the following Eclipse software URL to get the org.eclipse.linuxtools.man plug-in: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/updates-nightly/

Answer (score 3):

I found http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/wiki/Documentation/InstallGuide to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me in Indigo

1. Install DLTK Core from market place
2. Install the LinuxTools Man Page plugin from: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update
3. Install ShellEd from https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/shelled/shelled/ShellEd%202.0.1/update

Comment: The correct link for 3. is this one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/files/shelled/update/