# Problem installing ShellEd plugin in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, shell, eclipse-plugin

When I try to install ShellED plugin for Eclipse:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ShellEd 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97 (net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97)
  Missing requirement: ShellEd Core 0.0.0.201007201532 (net.sourceforge.shelled.core 0.0.0.201007201532) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.core [2.0.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ShellEd 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97 (net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group 2.0.0.201007201532-1--773533H735D97)
    To: net.sourceforge.shelled.core [0.0.0.201007201532]

Could not install org.eclipse.dltk.core? Do you know where to find it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have found http://www.chasetechnology.co.uk/eclipse/updates to be easier to install
After installing Linux Man page, install ShellEd from the above link.

```
go Help => install new software => Add 
Name: ShellEd 
Location: http://www.chasetechnology.co.uk/eclipse/updates
```

Restart eclipse 
close and reopen andy shell file and voala syntax highlighing will be there!!! 
Note that ShellEd does not create a new Perspective though. 
But *.sh, *.bash, *.csh, *.ksh and few other sh file extentions are associated to ShellEd.
Enjoy!!!

Comment: It worked for me but it seesm to be an older version of ShellEd. But it does syntax highlighting correctly.

Comment: It worked for me (at least the syntax highlighting). BTW, "voala" is spelled "voila" in French ;-)

Comment: Thanks -- this worked for me on an upgraded Galileo install that I don't have time to revamp right now.

Comment: The http://www.chasetechnology.co.uk/eclipse/updates link is now broken/dead.  In a few minutes of poking around there site, I was not able to find a live link to this update anymore.

Comment: It is version 1.0.0 How to install version 2.0.x? I am having problem installing the latest ShellED. says "requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.core [4.0.0,6.0.0)"

Comment: this is the latest link which worked for eclipse mars http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/5.4/

Answer (score 11):

go Help => install new software => Available Software sites
Remove http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update/
restart eclipse
go Help => install new software => Add

```
Name: Linuxtool
Location: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update
Select     Man Page Viewer (Incubation) 0.0.1.201102160611
```

you can now install shelled jar file

Comment: As of today, 27/03/2014, this is the right answer, surprisingly provided by the same user :)

Answer (score 6):

When I install newest ShellEd in eclipse Indigo, I got error like this:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ShellEd 2.0.2 (net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group 
2.0.2)Missing requirement: ShellEd Core Plug-in 2.0.0.201207181255
 (net.sourceforge.shelled.core 2.0.0.201207181255) requires 'bundle
 org.eclipse.dltk.core [4.0.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found.
```

We can know that it needs version 4 of Dynamic Languages Toolkit: org.eclipse.dltk.core [4.0.0,5.0.0), but it is possible that in indigo, version 3 is already installed (my case), and when I install lightly-build vertion 4 using url(http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/4.0-nightly/), it said only one core can be installed at once, which means eclipse will not update the version itself. So I uninstalled version 3 and install version 4, then ShellEd can be installed.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a command line to install the ShellEd plugin  (tested on ubuntu 12.04, eclipse Indigo):

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/,http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/4.0-nightly/,https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/shelled/shelled/ShellEd%202.0.2/update -installIU net.sourceforge.shelled.feature.group
```

If it fails, you may have an older version of dltk already installed that must be removed so that it will pull in the newer version from the dltk nightly builds repo.

Comment: Worked for me. Why can't Eclipse just do this?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are using Eclipse Helios release. The referenced dltk plugin released version 2.0 as part of Helios, so this ShellED plugin will not work on an earlier version of Eclipse. If you are using Helios, make sure that the "contact all update sites [etc]" checkbox in the install software dialog is checked. With this option enabled, Eclipse should be able to find the dependency.

DLTK: http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/

Comment: As mentioned I guess it means that the latest version of ShellEd needs to run on Eclipse Helios. For Galileo, the one mentioned in the other answer is working (Location: http://www.chasetechnology.co.uk/eclipse/updates)

Answer (score 2):

Probably, somebody still looking for solution around it for eclipse 3.5 or 3.6,
then, ShellEd 1.0.4 version can be installed easily:

1. Unzip the ShellEd1_0_4.zip
2. create a directory named ShellEd in eclipse >> dropins folder
3. move the unzipped directories (plugins, features) into eclipse >> dropins >> ShellEd
4. re/start the eclipse (onetime with -clean option)
5. these steps allows to make ShellEd1.0.4 version only, though, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.M3 still does not work.

Pre required plugins:

1. Linux tools:
   Linux Man page viewer 
   install using http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update
2. dltk (if its not available by default)
   install using http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates

Comment: Had issue, while installing Linux tools on my new eclipse environment. And here are few hints to locate the update site -

Linux tools doesn't gets using the URL http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update

Then, try to install Linux tools man page viewer with this URL
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/updates-nightly/
Or
http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/linuxtools/update/

This URL can be figured out by using
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/linuxtools/
and, pickup the Linux tools download or update install site URL.

Comment: Also, refer this page for Linux tools plugin install -
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PluginInstallHelp

Comment: This  worked for me on my Eclipse Indigo (Version: 3.7.1). Thanks! I was flowing the second post from @Kamikaze and installed Linux tools: Linux Man page viewer and then followed the steps 1 to 5 of this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me ..from the ShellED documentation. No other plugin was required

Using the update site

Use the regular install method with the following update site link https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/shelled/shelled/ShellEd%202.0.2/update

Comment: Was that quoted from the developer's [InstallGuide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/wiki/Documentation/InstallGuide)? The link has changed now to something that no longer works: `http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/files/shelled/update/`

Answer (score 0):

Shelled no longer exists.

Try ShellWax from the Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK) developers

https://github.com/eclipse/shellwax