# *nix Shell Editor for Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, shell, editor, syntax-highlighting

Had a quick look, but I can't find a good (any?) shell (sh, ksh, csh) editors for eclipse.

I've been doing a lot of editing of *.csh files recently, and it is bugging me having eclipse open them in the system default editor. I've changed that behaviour to be the default text editor in eclipse, but obviously there is no syntax highlighting.

I was initially just looking solely for some syntax highlighting, but have noticed while searching that there are entire plugins devoted to different file type development? Not sure what these provide though.

I'm not really sure what I'm looking for, but basically just a bit of colour.

GC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script plugin for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356827/bash-script-plugin-for-eclipse)

Comment: Possibly... I was hoping for something simple like syntax highlighting rather than a plugin. I used to use TextPad back when I used windows, and was able to download small configuration files to highlight for each file extension.

Comment: AFAIK there is no generic syntax highlighting for Eclipse except by installing a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://shelled.sourceforge.net/

Although I haven't used it for ages.  I tend to just use vi without all the colours and fancy stuff these days.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest Komodo for any kind of Programming- or Scripting-Language. Komodo itself is not free, but there is Komodoedit which is free and I'm using it since a long time for Shell scripting and Python programming and I won't switch back to eclipse or something else.

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

EDIT:

Seems like I didn't really read your question :s

I'm not a fan of eclispse, but I know you can embed gvim into eclise. Which is great if you are from the vim-camp.

Comment: It looks neat, but I can't be bothered having multiple editors! I have to use eclipse for loads of other work (custom plugin dev), that's why I was looking to bring my shell scripting into eclipse!