# eclipse sh edit and run

Tags: eclipse, bash, shell, sh

What would be the best way to run and edit a `.sh` script within Eclipse?

Regarding the editing part, I've found the ShellEd plugin, but it seems very minimalistic, is there no alternative?

Regarding the running part, I've found that there's a built in console that can be accessed by right clicking the `.sh`, then clicking 'remote system view', then clicking 'local'. But it's very minimalistic, there is not even tab completion. I would like something that could be as close to Bash as possible.

Comment: one of many reasons to ditch IDEs and use gmake :^\

Comment: I also would be very interested in an ShellEd alternative. ShellEd doesn't allow customizing colors. My black background in editor windows therefore renders it basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

You may find these two hyperlinks to be useful:

- http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/applications/132034-running-shellscripts-eclipse.html
- [Bash script plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356827/bash-script-plugin-for-eclipse)

I do not know much about Eclipse. I prefer Geany; however, it does not execute shell scripts.