# Is there a way to convert multiple variable declarations to one per line?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

In Eclipse, is there an automatic way to convert this:

```
int myX, myY, myZ;
```

... to this...

```
int myX;
int myY;
int myZ;
```

I thought I could do this from the 'Clean Up' and 'Members Sort Order' preferences, but it does not break up the multiple declarations into one per line.  Is there a way to do it?

Edit: To clarify, this is in regards to member variables.

Comment: i dont think format will do this for you, tho you might be able to create a formatting rule (you can do that right?)

Comment: Do you insist on an Eclipse answer?

Comment: @IraBaxter I'm most interested in a way to do it via Eclipse, but if another IDE is the only way, I'd still like to hear it.

Comment: How many times would you have to do this? i.e. how many variables are you doing this to?

Comment: What is your purpose of having a tool that accomplishes this? (i.e. why do you want variable declarations on separate lines?)

Comment: @Ryan One-per-line abides by Java conventions (see the answer below that states Checkstyle will flag multiple declarations).  It's considered to have less potential for confusion.

Comment: @Noob Thousands across hundreds of class files.

Comment: @whiskeyspider Unfortunately I cannot be of much help as I've never used Eclipse, but I am with you in spirit as you stare down this great task.

Answer (score 7):

While I don't know if a *single* function which does this, you can obtain similar results with a few keystrokes:

1. Highlight the line which contains the multiple variable definitions, and use the **Find/Replace** function (keystroke: `Ctrl-F`) to replace the comma-space sequence to a semicolon, space and the type of the variable. Make sure the scope is set to "selected lines" as in the following screenshot:

   [image: Find replace dialog]
2. Now you'll still have a line with all the variable declarations in a single line. This can be fixed by highlighting the same line and the **Source > Format** function (keystroke: `Shift-Ctrl-F`).

   [image: Source format menu]
3. All done, now you have your variables with their respective type, one per line:

   [image: All done]

Comment: This method is useless in anything larger then the most trivial of files.

Comment: I'd make the find and replace step a regex that looks for comma plus optional whitespace.

Comment: I think @E-Riz answer would ultimately be best solution, but this worked as a fast, dead-simple fix for this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @whiskeyspider: I think you'll find it pretty hard to use this method for "Thousands across hundreds of class files." :)

Comment: @skarist It's not a solution that will work automatically across all of the classes, but on a class-by-class basis -- since I already had a formatter ready -- it did save time.

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in Clean Up or Formatter option to do that (which surprises me). However, writing a plugin to do it would not be terribly difficult. For reference, you'd start with [this extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_contributing_a_cleanup.htm). The class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.fix.VariableDeclarationCleanUp` looks like a potential one to study as an example and guide.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse does not provide this formatting feature out of the box. You can use `Checkstyle` plugin to check for this and many more coding standards.

In Checkstyle configuration file, use module `MultipleVariableDeclarations` like this,

```xml
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <property name="cacheFile" value="target/cachefile"/>
        <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
        ...
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
        ...
    </module>
</module>
```

If you are OK with command line tool, then `astyle` and `GC GreatCode` are two good code formatters.

`GC GreatCode` is given as C/C++ code formatter but it will format your code in this scenario well.

In `GC` the option to split variable declaration is `-code_split_decl_style`

Original code:

```
String fileName, a, b, c;
```

With `-code_split_decl_style-1` option:

```
String  fileName,
        a,
        b,
        c;
```

With `-code_split_decl_style-2` option:

```
String fileName;
String a;
String b;
String c;
```

You can play around with different command line formatting tools and configurations for various languages in one GUI tool using `UniversalIndentGUI`.

---

Checkstyle: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/

Astyle: astyle.sourceforge.net/

GC GreateCode: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcgreatcode/

UniversalIndentGUI: universalindent.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse doesn't seem to provide a function for this, and I haven't found a plugin that does this. But assuming that you have access to awk, you might find this little awk script helpful:

```
{
  if (match($0,/([a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]+)\s+(([a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]+)\s*,\s*)+([a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]+);/)) {
    match($0,/(\s*[a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]+)\s+([^;]*)/,components);
    split(components[2],vars,",");
    for(i in vars) {
      gsub (/'[[:cntrl:]]|[[:space:]]|\x20/,"",vars[i])
      print components[1],vars[i]";"
    }
  }
  else {
   print $0;
  }
}
```

It will do the required job. Assuming you save it to the file *script.awk* you would call it like this

```
awk -f script.awk target_file.java
```

NOTE: you must direct the output to an alternate file or your source will be overwritten (emptied)

So if you want to process a number of files at one go you should do it like this (assuming a bash shell):

```
for f in *.java; do awk -f awk1.awk $f > $f.pr; done
```

For each java file this will create a new file with the ending .java.pr, and then you just move those over into files with a .java ending.

================== EDIT =================

Just want to add that there exist plug-ins for Eclipse that support bash/awk scripts over a selected region.  See here:

http://eclipseexeditor.sourceforge.net/ 
(probably to old for newer versions of Eclipse)

and here also:

[Bash script plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356827/bash-script-plugin-for-eclipse).

So, my script coupled with one of those plug-ins would presumably add the requested feature to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box such feature in Eclipse that I know of.

I assume you are a java programmer and hence your best bet would be to write a simple program that will parse out source code for such pattern and convert it to multi-line as desired. Then run clean up on top of it to have it properly formatted as required.