# how to install shelled in eclipse luna

Tags: bash, shell, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install shelled in the latest Eclipse Luna and I am getting the following error:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.cpp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.java7,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.java7,3.7.1.201504261725-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.slf4j.impl.log4j12,1.7.2.v20131105-2200
```

I have tried to install it locally from archive and also [Bash script plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356827/bash-script-plugin-for-eclipse), but and all of this failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to install it by deleting eclipse luna and downloading it again from scratch... I still don't understand why I got the errors in my old eclipse... It is rather annoying since I had a lot of plugins installed in my old eclipse and I had to re-install them all over again (this time I installed shelled first to eliminate the possibility that one of the plugins interfering with shelled installation...). Looks like a bug in eclipse (or one of its plugins) to me.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue for Luna (4.4.2.M20150204-1700), I had to install dltk :

go Help => install,  new software => Add

```
Name: DLTK

Location: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/5.3.1/
```

I choose only the first checkbox :"Dynamic Languages Toolkit Core Frameworks"

Then I installed [ShellEd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/) by following this tutorial : [how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip).

Answer (score 0):

try to downlaod the plugin manually from the update site, then follow the instructions here: [how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I installed `shelled` on `Eclipse Luna` successfully.

**Steps:**

- Update site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/files/shelled/update/
- Check option: ***Contact all update sites during install to find required software***
- Install, it will take a while to finish downloading & installation, *(maybe 20 minutes eveb with a good network)*.
- Restart eclipse.
- Ok

**Tips:**

- The key part it to check the option mentioned above, otherwise it will fail. Even though it's slow and not necessary for most other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a good shell editor plugin for eclipse, here it is :

```
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=3261650
```

Just drag the "install" button to eclipse workspace. It will automate the installation.